# How to educate people to include complete error messages

Tags: discussion, answers, low-quality-posts

One thing that happens very frequently on SO (and also on other programming and computing websites where people ask questions) is that someone will write a question in the form:

> I did ... and there was **an error**. What is wrong / how do I fix it?

The person asking the question doesn't seem to realize that the actual error message contains important information to diagnose the problem.

What is a good way to educate people that error messages are important and that they should always include detailed information, and how to learn them to read and interpret error messages?

Comment: I plan to write a canonical post on .NET exceptions. Part of it will be "no, you did _not_ get an error; instead, an _exception_ was _thrown_". Of course, I have planned to write this post for months now. It would be something to expound on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689049/how-to-create-berkeley-database-using-net#comment49437647_30689049.

Comment: I think the only way to get those wannabe/havetobe "programmers" to pay even minimal attention to those details involves repeated application of the famous LART.

Comment: The most sure-fire way is to actually ask for it. If they need help and the community needs the error message to help them then they either provide it or go wanting. They normally will, but far too late... at which point the question gets closed/deleted and everyone has had a bad experience. Giving newer users a reason to stick around to post the error message, and the code, and the everything else they're bound to forget when it's requested might be more helpful.

Comment: I think the best form of _education_ you can give them is to down and close vote such questions. As soon they'll see the reason on the [on hold] message, they'll realize what they did wrong (and hopefully will improve with their next question, or edit the current one). Sometimes I also leave a comment asking explicitly for the exact errors. But most of the time I just use the former action.

Comment: I'm working on a method for punching people through the innertubes. That way, when they do this or when they post an image of the exception helper dialog ... ***WHAM!***

Comment: It is one of the points in [How do I create an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Hold on, do you mean people don't read that either?

Comment: *I tried RTFM but it did not work*

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I find most of the time, questions that do not include the actual error message are VLQ to begin with. With C/C++ for example, they generally are either because of a complete lack of basic understanding of the language and/or tools, or what comes down to a simple typo or other silly mistake. Neither of these types of questions/answers are likely to be useful to future readers.

Trying to add more instructions on asking I think is a losing proposition. The site help on asking questions is enough. If a user doesn't read it, or doesn't realize that the text of an error message is extremely important information, they run the risk of down/close voting, at the cost of their reputation.

If you feel altruistic, ask them to edit their question and add the message text. If they give it as a comment instead, you can edit their question and include it. If you don't feel generous, downvote/flag the question. Either is acceptable behavior.

Comment: One minor point: rather than asking for the information and then editing it yourself, encourage the author to edit directly. A tip towards this end is that a comment with the text `[edit]` produces a link to edit its parent post, like so: [edit]. Thus you can write something like `Please [edit] your post to include the complete text of the error message.`

Comment: @JoshCaswell: that snippet of information crudely bit me back when I suggested it in a comment under my *own* answer. The OP did what I asked and edited *my answer*. Hilarity ensued.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include how to include a link to `[edit]` a comment.